# Выпадающий список в телеграмм боте

Tags: python, aiogram, бот, telegram

Как сделать такой выпадающий список используя Python, Aiogram.
ВАЖНО список можно менять в зависимости от того где он используется

[image: фото]

Comment: [Как я понял, выдает содержимое этого списка](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputinvoicemessagecontent). [То что позволяет понять, что выбрал пользователь](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#choseninlineresult). [Пример](https://telegrambots.github.io/book/3/inline.html)